# About centering to accommodate multicollinearity (Ordinal Logistic Regression Analysis, Logistic Regression Analysis)

Tags: logistic, interaction, multicollinearity, centering

When interaction terms are used in multiple regression analysis, often centralization of the variables (subtracting the mean of the variable from each variable) is used to deal with multicollinearity, Can this method (centering) also be used in logistic regression analysis and ordinal logistic regression analysis?